# Cyclic animation of objects along a path using the tikz decorations library and animate

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate, decorations

How could a cyclic animation be achieved using the tikz decorations library and animate? The simple example shows circles moving around the perimeter of a square (the resulting animation is shown below). The desired result should be a continuous, looping animation without "disappearing" circles.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage[export]{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{24}
    \multiframe{160}{rt=0+0.0125*180}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            [
            decoration={markings, mark=between positions {0+\rt/360} and 1 step .4 cm with {\draw circle [radius=.05cm];}},
            ]
            \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle ++(3,3);
            \draw [decorate] (0.5,0.5) rectangle ++(2,2); 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should it be all circles always with no gap (like in your animation)? Then you don't need all the frames but the few first ones.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: indeed. Thank you. It has also been answered by AlexG below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy. Just reduce the number of frames to 8:

```
\multiframe{8}{rt=0+0.0125*180}{
  ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: @tosogoso The cycle length is 8 frames. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer! I should have thought about that ;).

Comment: Actually, @Qrrbrbirlbel beat me by seconds with his comment.